# Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding error - tree printing

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm having some trouble creating a function to print the contents of a Tree. My definition for the data type Tree is as follows:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

The code for printing the tree is:

```
printTree :: Tree a -> String
printTree (Node a left right) = printTreeAux (Node a left right) 0

printTreeAux :: Tree a -> Int -> String
printTreeAux EmptyTree _ = ""
printTreeAux (Node a left right) depth = (replicate (6 * depth) ' ') ++ show a ++ "\n" ++ (printTreeAux left (depth + 1)) ++ "\n" ++ (printTreeAux right (depth + 1))
```

And I'm getting the following error when loading the file to Hugs:

```
ERROR file:.\Tree.hs:30 - Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : printTreeAux
*** Type          : Tree a -> Int -> String
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : Show a
```

I already searched for some clarification but found nothing that could really help...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
printTree :: Tree a -> String
printTree (Node a left right) = printTreeAux (Node a left right) 0
```

to:

```
printTree :: Tree a -> String
printTree x = printTreeAux x 0
```

or even better:

```
printTree :: Tree a -> String
printTree = (flip printTreeAux) 0
```

There's no need to pattern match on `printTree` as you are forwarding the argument to `printTreeAux`. In fact with your pattern matching, `EmptyTree` will never be matched in `printTree` and therefore generate an error.

You should also add a constraint on `a` to request that it's `Show`able, otherwise `show a` is not going to compile:

```
printTree :: (Show a) => Tree a -> String
```

and:

```
printTreeAux :: (Show a) => Tree a -> Int -> String
```

As [you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/394a29e7c72cbc74), with those fixes, the program will compile, and [run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fd508f26a09bb83), just fine.